# umake Arguments not listed Android

Tags: 16.04, android, ubuntu-make

I refer the [umake tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make).

```
aboo@aboo-Aspire-E5-511:~$ sudo apt install ubuntu-make
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-make is already the newest version (16.11.1~xenial1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Then type `umake android`:

```
aboo@aboo-Aspire-E5-511:~$ umake android
usage: umake [--help] [-v] [-r] [--version]
         {dart,nodejs,rust,web,ide,go,games} ...
umake: error: argument category: invalid choice: 'android' (choose from 'dart', 'nodejs', 'rust', 'web', 'ide', 'go', 'games')
```

How do I install android sdk using umake?

Comment: yes.. umake android getting error ?

Comment: umake android android-sdk